# Form data is not stored in DB

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :itemable, :adults, :children
  belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :lead
  belongs_to :cart


end


class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end

end


class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :itemable
end

class Appartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :as => :itemable
end
```

item_controller

```
def create
      @line_item = @cart.line_items.build itemable: @object
      respond_to do |format|
        if @line_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
            notice: 'Vakantiehuis toegevoegd in lijst.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show',
            status: :created, location: @line_item }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
            status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
   end

private
    def create_object
      id = params[:house_id] || params[:appartment_id]

      model = "House" if params[:house_id]
      model = "Apartment" if params[:appartment_id]
      model = model.constantize

      @object = model.find(id)
   end
```

lead_controller

```
def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    @lead.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
    @lead.save

  end
```

cart_controller

```
def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)
end

private
def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end
```

When the items are added from the house and aparment page..the visitor goes to the cart show template. The visitor can fill in number of adutls and children by a form (select).

```
- @cart.line_items.each do |item|
    %tr.CartProduct


      %td
        .CartDescription
          %p
            = link_to item.itemable.name, polymorphic_url([item.itemable.country, item.itemable.region, item.itemable])
      %td.CartProductThumb
        %div
        - item.itemable.attachments.take(1).each do |a|
          = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url(:thumb)))   





      %td 
        .col-md-10
          = form_for(item) do |f|   
            = f.select :adults, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], :class => 'form-control'

      %td 

        .col-md-10
          = form_for(item) do |f|   
            = f.select :children, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], :class => 'form-control'

    = button_to "Checkout", new_lead_path, method: :get
```

The [cart_id] and the polymorphic [itemable_type][itemable_id]values are correctly stored in the line_items table, but not the form data :adults and children. What am i doing wrong ? Thanks remco

logfile:

```
Started POST "/nl/leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-04 11:55:25 +0200
Processing by LeadsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jmWa/Q/+SGsS+ed7zEB5+w5tiY2ywkEx3dQeVt9roKs=", "lead"=>{"firstname"=>"test ", "lastname"=>"", "email"=>"", "extra"=>"", "telephone"=>""}, "commit"=>"submit", "nl"=>"nl"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 25 LIMIT 1
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`cart_id` = 25
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `leads` (`created_at`, `email`, `extra`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `telephone`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-09-04 09:55:25', '', '', 'test ', '', '', '2014-09-04 09:55:25')
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `line_items` SET `lead_id` = 8, `updated_at` = '2014-09-04 09:55:25' WHERE `line_items`.`id` = 191
   (8.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/nl/leads/8
Completed 302 Found in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

Comment: Please post the log for the post request you're making to your controller.

Comment: It looks like you are having problems with [parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). Try `params[:cart].permit!` - also like @BroiSatse said - share your `log/development.log` with us.

Comment: @OtoBrglez - It's rails 3, no strong parameters here.

Comment: no it is rails 4 ...

Comment: @Remco - If it is rails 4, why do you use `attr_accessible` in your model? Your `cart_params` are incorrect and would cause `Cart.new(cart_params)` to throw an exception. Another question: why do you have two forms for the same item in your view?

Comment: @Remco - Your logs are stating that lead was inserted into leads table.

Comment: yes..thats correct..and a lead has_many line_items...the items as house is stored correct, but not the form data as adults and children at the line item. Every line_item can have different values as in adults and children..thats why a from.